# I can't open the green filename files from my desktop where Window7 was installed

Tags: filesystems

I copy the green filename files of any type from my notebook where O.S. is Windows XP and open it from another desktop where Window7 was installed, but it return me an error. I can't open at all. Is this VIRUS infected files, how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: What on earth are 'green filename files'?

Comment: Files with a green filename are encrypted. You need to have the correct keys to be able to open them. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307877

Comment: @ChrisF - That's the correct answer isn't it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Files with a green filename are encrypted. You need to have the correct keys/permissions to be able to open them.

See this [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307877) for more information.